# Windows Authentication on ASP.net application

Tags: asp.net, iis, active-directory, iis-10

I have a strange issue with aps.net which using windows Authentication, here is the scenario, I have APS.net application using the Windows Authentication, NTLM ... all my users on the Active Directory have access to the web application when they want, the issue that sometimes some users can't access to the system anymore, where they used to have access before, when they put their username@domain and the password in the pop-up login in the browser, the pop-up keep popping up like they have put a wrong username or password, we tried to log in to other services like email, laptop, using the same user name and password and it works fine, but not with the web application! any idea how or where to start my investigation? logs file? something similar? here is my IIS authentication setting:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: That's rather common because your site configuration might trigger error responses such as 401.3 or 401.5 to those users and the browser will prompt (just like it sees 401.2 or 401.1). At this very moment, study IIS log files to see what exactly were the error codes/substatus codes for those users, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/http-status-code

Comment: Is the HTTP response code 401 or 403? A 403 means that authentication worked, but authorization failed (i.e. "I know who you are, but you're not allowed to view this page"). A 403 will, by default, also trigger the login pop-up.

Comment: May be some users that are member of many groups for which the `maxtokensize` should be increased. See [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/kerberos-authentication-problems-if-user-belongs-to-groups)

Comment: Different status code means different problem. So you need to make sure the status code first. You can get this from IIS log or development mode of browser.

Comment: I've checked the devMode on chrome and I got 401 Error code?! how come? he is using the same username and pass to log-in to other services!

Comment: Try to use this in web.config: `<security>
        <authorization>
            <add accessType="Allow" users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </security>`

Answer (score 0):

After many days of investigating the issue, it turned out that the issue is because of expired password.